# Eliminate matrix header in esttab (latex) or outtable output

Tags: matrix, latex, stata

I have a matrix of values (very non-standard summary statistics) that I want to pass from Stata to LaTeX. The command:

```
esttab matrix(matname) using $myfilename.tex, replace booktabs f
```

gives the matrix in LaTeX form but also gives the title of the matrix within the fragment. The same is true for:

```
outtable using myfilename, mat(matname) replace nobox
```

Currently, every time I rerun my Stata do file I have to go and edit myfilename.tex by hand.

**Is there any way to non-manually remove the matrix name from the Stata to LaTeX output?**

I tried using the option noheader, which works here:

```
matrix list matname, noheader
```

but doesn't seem to be active in esttab or outtable. It also occurred to me that if I could find a way to ask LaTex to just \input PART of the fragment file (lines 2 onward) that would work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the nomtitles option will work. Here's reproducible example:

```
sysuse auto
reg price trunk headroom
matrix myMat = e(V)

esttab matrix(myMat) using temp.tex, replace booktabs f nomtitles
```

This produces the text (.tex) file below:

```
            &       trunk&    headroom&       \_cons\\
\midrule
trunk       &    10557.96&   -35339.31&   -39464.18\\
headroom    &   -35339.31&    269901.5&   -321726.7\\
\_cons      &   -39464.18&   -321726.7&     1612951\\
```

Also, I used the following `outtable` command

```
outtable using "./temp", mat(myMat) replace center f(%9.2f) nobox
```

to produce this output:

```
% matrix: myMat file: ./temp.tex  10 Jun 2016 12:55:35
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{lccc} \hline \hline
 & trunk  & headroom  & cons  \\  \hline 
trunk &  10557.96 \\  
headroom & -35339.31 & 269901.52 \\  
cons & -39464.18 & -3.22e+05 &  1.61e+06 \\  
\hline \hline \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

While the matrix name is present in the output, it is commented out and so will not appear in the latex document.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works! I wasn't thinking of it as a model title.